# Seed ASP.NET Identity user and roles in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am following [this tutorial](https://frankofoedu.medium.com/how-to-seed-identity-role-with-associated-user-in-asp-net-core-ef-core-e40ecd643d0f) to seed ASP.NET Identity user and roles in .NET Core 3.1

But when I add migration, I got exception

> PM> add-migration seed -context ApplicationDbContext Build started...
> Build succeeded. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
> 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined. If
> you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder
> modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
> accessor)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
> factory)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
> contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
> name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
> name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary
> key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call
> 'HasNoKey()'. PM>

This is my code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            string ADMIN_ID = "02174cf0–9412–4cfe-afbf-59f706d72cf6";
            string ROLE_ID = "341743f0-asd2–42de-afbf-59kmkkmk72cf6";

            //seed admin role
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
            {
                Name = "SuperAdmin",
                NormalizedName = "SuperAdmin",
                Id = ROLE_ID,
                ConcurrencyStamp = ROLE_ID
            });

            //create user
            var appUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = ADMIN_ID,
                Email = "frankofoedu@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,                
                UserName = "frankofoedu@gmail.com"
            };

            //set user password
            PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> ph = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            appUser.PasswordHash = ph.HashPassword(appUser, "mypassword_?");

            //seed user
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(appUser);

            //set user role to admin
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = ROLE_ID,
                UserId = ADMIN_ID
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey man you saved a lot of my time... Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to comment in

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

Comment: Please re-apply the code (comment in). BR